# Texstudio compiling time

Tags: pdftex, compiling

I have been using TexStudio for the past month and very much enjoy the program. I recently ran a 20 page long manuscript with 7 diagrams and  4 tables. Till about a couple of hours ago it was working fine compiling and generating the pdf. All of a sudden it started giving me the following error message

```
"Process started: pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "combreport".tex "
```

Ever since the message has come, the pdf file hasn't generated. It is still compiling even though its taken more than half-an-hour .
This is a new file that gets generated "combreport.synctex.gz(busy)"

After a complete restart, texstudio is taking more than 5 min to load.

I have tried reinstalling it but no use.I have tried running the script through Texmaker also but the result is the same.

This is how I begin

```
% !TXS template
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[lofdepth,lotdepth]{subfig}
\newlength\tindent
\setlength{\tindent}{\parindent}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\indent}{\hspace*{\tindent}}

\newcommand{\Mypm}{\mathbin{\tikz [x=1.4ex,y=1.4ex,line width=.1ex] \draw (0.0,0) -- (1.0,0) (0.5,0.08) -- (0.5,0.92) (0.0,0.5) -- (1.0,0.5);}}%

\title{Report on Analysis of 6994}
\author{Bn Rh Ma}

\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    \section{Introduction}
```

Comment: Do you have the same behaviour with another file? The problem doesn't come from TeXstudio itself (it's only an editor, with a script to launch the compiler). Probably, your  source code has some syntax error which makes pdflatex enter an infinite loop. Could you post a *minimal* (non-) working code?

Comment: This code (completed with `\end{document}`) is perfectly normal and compiles regularly.

Comment: I see no mention of `biblatex` in your question other than the tag, so I have removed said tag. If you *are* talking about `biblatex`, please make that more specific in your question. The code snippet you posted does not create any problems when completed to a minimal document. So please prepare a proper [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864). Can you get more specific error messages from the `.log` file?